# Pug.js - convert <a> tag in string to a link

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

An API I'm using returns a string which can also include an `<a />` tag with a link. Whenever I render this in Pug, the hyperlink renders as plain text and is unclickable.

Is there any way I can convert the link in the text to an actual link?

Example string: `Major disruption through Rugby. More details can be found in <A href="http://nationalrail.co.uk/service_disruptions/166412.aspx">Latest Travel News.</A>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually depends on how you include this text in the template, but I think you've come across [escaped String interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html). What happens is that Pug automatically 'sanitizes' the input it gets when you do `p= [input variable...]`. That sanitization-step also includes making `<>` characters 'disfunctional' in the HTML-sense. This prevents a range of attacks, most notably one where actual script code could have been inserted into your page.

If you, however, fully trust this API/data-source, you could choose to leave the input strings [unescaped](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped). How safe this option is depends on how much control you have over that API or how much you trust it.

Other options without leaving input unescaped could include doing manual regex searches for `<a ...>` tags and converting matches to that regex into actual links with some JS code.

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! Thank you.